# Split the data between the Training Data and Test Data using sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, training

**Work to do**

My job is to take the data and divide it between Training and Test using 30% of the data as Test where both should have the same ratio between positive and negative.

**CSV File**

```
age,Feature 2,Feature 3,Feature 4,income,Feature 6,Feature 7,Feature 8,Feature 9,Feature 10,Feature 11,Feature 12,Feature 13,Feature 14,Feature 15,Class
77,1,0,0,3,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0
35,1,0,1,4,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0
79,1,0,0,2,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1
61,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0
62,0,0,0,2,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1
63,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1
29,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0
39,0,1,1,5,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0
51,0,1,1,6,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1
```

**Code - Training Data and Test Data**

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer


# Reading CVS file
dataSet = pd.read_csv('./TestDataFile_ML.csv')
X = dataSet.iloc[:,:-1].values
y = dataSet.iloc[:,15].values


df = pd.DataFrame(dataSet)
print(df)

# Missing data
imputer = Imputer(missing_values="NaN" , strategy="mean" , axis=0)


# Split the data between the Training Data and Test Data
xTrain , xTest , yTrain , yTest = train_test_split(X , y , test_size = 0.30 , random_state = 0)


# Creating linear regression object
linearReg = LinearRegression()
linearReg.fit(xTrain , yTrain)

#Now, testing model
yPrediction = linearReg.predict(xTest)


print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)
print(xTrain , yTrain)

#Plotting the training set
plot.scatter(xTrain , yTrain , color="red")
plot.plot(xTrain , linearReg.predict(xTrain) , color="blue")
plot.title("title")
plot.xlabel("x label")
plot.ylabel("y label")
plot.show()

# Test set
plot.scatter(xTest, yTest, color = 'red')
plot.plot(xTrain, linearReg.predict(xTrain), color = 'blue')
plot.title("title")
plot.xlabel("x label")
plot.ylabel("y label")
plot.show()
```

**Problems found**

The following error is showing me:
ValueError: x and y must be the same size

This is because apparently in the part of

```
X = dataSet.iloc [:,: - 1] .values
y = dataSet.iloc [:, 15] .values
```

I'm not taking the correct values. If someone can help me to correct the error I will thank you

**Updates**

After adding`stratify = y` to:

```
xTrain , xTest , yTrain , yTest = train_test_split(X , y , test_size = 0.30, random_state = 0 , stratify = y)
```

It shows me the following graph, in which I presume that it is incorrect
[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called [Stratified sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling)

From this [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/250273/36415) question, we have a short explanation

> Stratified sampling aims at splitting one data set so that each split
>   are similar with respect to something. In a classification setting, it
>   is often chosen to ensure that the train and test sets have
>   approximately the same percentage of samples of each target class as
>   the complete set.

To get a stratified split in ScikitLearn, you just need to edit this part of your code

```
# Split the data between the Training Data and Test Data
xTrain , xTest , yTrain , yTest = train_test_split(X , y , 
                                                  test_size = 0.30 , 
                                                  random_state = 0, 
                                          ----->  stratify = y)
```

This will automatically split your dataset in train and test but also keep the same proportion of positives and negatives as the original dataset.

So, if you have a dataset where the positive class is 70% of the records and negative class 30%, after a stratified split, both train and test will have the same 70-30 distribution.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information, very valuable.

My only problem is that when the graphics are generated it shows me many lines in different directions.

Comment: I just did update, I added the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Just print type of both `xTest` and `yTest`. You should see that both are of different type. Or simply print both of them. You should be able to see that they are indeed different.

I think using `xTest[:,0]` for plotting should solve the problem.

The same thing applies for `xTrain`.

Comment: Sorry, in which part of the code you recommend me to make the change for xTest [:, 0]?

Comment: you have to change both xTest and xTrain. The following should solve your problem:

plot.scatter(xTrain[:,0], yTrain , color="red")

Comment: Thanks, I just fixed it.

But looking at the graphics, I think the results are incorrect.

Comment: What I want to achieve is  to take the data and divide it between Training and Test using 30% of the data as Test where both should have the same ratio between positive and negative.

Comment: use: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedShuffleSplit

Or
train_test_split(X , y , test_size = 0.30 , random_state = 0, stratify=y)

Comment: For you this part is correct?

X = dataSet.iloc [:,: - 1] .values
y = dataSet.iloc [:, 15] .values

Comment: Yeah, I didn't get any error in that part.

Comment: I still think that my implementation is wrong, because the graphics shows me lines in different directions.

There will be no other solution for what I want to achieve?
Sorry, I'm new to these topics.

Comment: Use google to find answers. We have already deviated a lot from your original question and I am sorry but I can't spoonfeed you everything. All the best. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add here that it is important to remember the **Blind Test Rule**. In particular, in order to avoid accidentally optimising your code for the test data during development, a golden rule is to split the data set in three datasets:

1. Train dataset, to do the training (i.e. 60%)
2. Validation dataset, to test during development (i.e. 20%), and
3. Test dataset, to do the final testing **only** at the end of the development (i.e. 20%).